# Reverse Camera - White Screen When lights turn on

Tags: lights, camera, dashcam

I wired in a dash cam / reverse cam into a 2004 Ford Fiesta.

The cameras work fine except the rear camera turns completely white when I switch on the cars lights.

The reverse camera receives power from the dashcam normally and receives power for 4 LED's and to trigger the camera to display on screen via the reverse light. I have the camera wired to the reverse light +12v and the ground on the rear light loom.

Any ideas why it whites out when the lights are turned on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Try disconnecting the four LED's and see if it helps. Also, does the camera switch over to infrared when the lights are turned on? If so, it could just be getting washed out. Also, it might help if you indicated which camera system you installed on your Fiesta.

Comment: The 4 LED's are part of the camera unit. Camera is powered via it's AV cable that connects to the dash cam. The LED's only powers on when reverse gear is selected (drawing power from the reverse light's wiring) and it also triggers the camera to be displayed on the screen. I can turn on the rear camera without being in reverse gear by selecting one of the buttons on the dash cam. It is not possible that the LED's are washing out the image because if the car is in neutral and the headlights are switched on  the image turns white (the LED's only activate if the car is put into reverse gear).

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dashboard-FUNANASUN-Recorder-Recording-Detection-Mirror-cam/dp/B076BRBX1W/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1534688309&sr=8-3&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65&keywords=dash+cam+rear+view+mirror

Comment: I've drawn a description of what happens: https://ibb.co/kydmne